# How to use backspace which stops at the number 0

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am trying to create a backspace button (for a calculator) that when pressed, can only backspace until the textbox has reached 0.

i don't know what else to add, so far I am at:

```
displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
```

so far its able to backspace to " " then eventually crashes if used again.

i wish to limit the backspace button so if there's no more text entered in the field, it will automatically change the text to "0".

Answered, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

```
private void backSpaceButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(displaytxt.Text))
    {
        displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to end up with an empty string. This does give the OP an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply check before calling substring

```
if(string.Empty != displaytxt.Text)
   displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
```

or you can check the length

```
if(displaytxt.Text.Length > 0)
  displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to never get an empty string, you want to get `"0"` if you backspace while you only have a single character left. So, check if you have a single-character string:

```
if (displaytxt.Text.Length == 1)
  displaytxt.Text = "0";
else
  displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
```

Note: make sure you don't have any other code that sets `displaytxt.Text` to an empty string.

Comment: sweet thanks, i tried a couple of these and this one is what i wanted. THANKS! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to emulate ***BackSpace*** ***key*** you can do something like that:

```
private void backSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (displaytxt.SelectionLength > 0)
    displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Remove(displaytxt.SelectionStart, displaytxt.SelectionLength);
  else if (displaytxt.SelectionStart > 0) {
    int start = displaytxt.SelectionStart;

    displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Remove(start - 1, 1);
    displaytxt.Select(start - 1, 0);
  }
}
```

If you want just to remove ***the last char*** you can achive it

```
private void backSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(displaytxt.Text))
    displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Remove(displaytxt.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
displaytxt.Text = displaytxt.Text.Length > 1 ? 
                    displaytxt.Text.Substring(0, displaytxt.Text.Length - 1) : 
                    "0";
```